# Rails Multiple URI Pattern for the same Devise Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise, routes

I'm using Devise in my project and I originally started it back in 2013 with API Version 1 (api/v1/).  I'm not having to create a version 2 (api/v2/) and I'm having issues figuring out how to go about creating the new v2 routes for devise.

Both /api/v1/ and /api/v2/ are pointing to the same users model, but I have them going through different controllers.  Currently below is what I'm trying, but I get the message "Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session'".

[image: The controller setup]

The scoped route for /api/v1/

```
scope '/api' do
   scope '/v1' do
       devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "devise/v1/users_registrations",
                                      :sessions => "devise/v1/users_sessions",
                                      :passwords => "devise/v1/users_passwords"}
   end
end
```

The scoped route for /api/v2/

```
scope '/api' do
   scope '/v2' do
       devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "devise/v2/users_registrations",
                                      :sessions => "devise/v2/users_sessions",
                                      :passwords => "devise/v2users_passwords"}
   end
```

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `namespace` along-side or instead of the scope.

Right now those scopes will change the location of the files themselves yet do not update the actual pathing names so you are getting a duplicate error.

I.E.

```
scope :api do
   namespace :v1 do
       devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "devise/v1/users_registrations",
                                      sessions: "devise/v1/users_sessions",
                                      passwords: "devise/v1/users_passwords"}
   end
end



scope :api do
   namespace :v2 do
       devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "devise/v2/users_registrations",
                                      sessions: "devise/v2/users_sessions",
                                      passwords: "devise/v2/users_passwords"}
   end
end
```

Then your routes would be `new_v1_user_session` and `new_v2_user_session`, etc...

Comment: Thank you, this does get me past the Invalid route name issue, but I then run into another issue.  In devises helpers.rb devise_parameter_sanitizer it seems to expect the params to come in with key 'v1_user', but the key is still 'user'.  Devise::ParameterSanitizer.new(resource_class, resource_name, params)   Here resource_name is 'v1_user' and the params has all the information needed with key 'user'.  Any idea what's going on?   I might need to start a new question for this one.

Comment: Open a new question for this one and I'll help you dig into it

Comment: Add the link in the comments to I can find it.

Comment: Just opened the new question here, http://stackoverflow.com/q/34776486/703910
Thank you!